# Sort vertices of multiple quadrilaterals

Tags: c++, sorting

[image]

Here is my function which can sort the vertices of a quadrilateral in the order top left --> top right --> bottom right --> bottom left:

```
void sortCornors(Point center, vector<Point> LEDPoints,        vector<Point2f> &newLEDPoints)
{
    vector<Point2f> top;
    vector<Point2f> bottom;

    for (int i = 0; i < LEDPoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (LEDPoints[i].y < center.y)
            top.push_back(LEDPoints[i]);
        else
            bottom.push_back(LEDPoints[i]);
    }

    Point2f tl = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[1] : top[0];
    Point2f tr = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[0] : top[1];
    Point2f bl = bottom[0].x > bottom[1].x ? bottom[1] : bottom[0];
    Point2f br = bottom[0].x > bottom[1].x ? bottom[0] : bottom[1];

    newLEDPoints.push_back(tl);
    newLEDPoints.push_back(tr);
    newLEDPoints.push_back(br);
    newLEDPoints.push_back(bl);
}
```

The center is computed as follows (for four vertices):

```
for (int i = 0; i < LEDPoints.size(); ++i)
{
    center += LEDPoints[i];
}

center *= (1.0 / LEDPoints.size());
```

I need an elegant solution (may be a recursive  version of this solution) which works for any number of quadrilaterals. which means if there are two quadrilaterals they should be sorted in similar order.

Comment: You think people would be asking loads of questions with the tag quadrilateral and others searching with them? If so, the tags would already be there.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen now the only words i could find relevant to my question are c++ and sorting which don't describe my question completely. You need to see both sides of the coin.

Comment: That's why people write titles for the questions also. That's the most visible part, not the tags.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Ok got your point. can you please help me with my actual problem? :)

Comment: There's no "vertices" tag because that's a plural, which I'd like to add as additional reason. Now, back to your problem: What is the preferred sorting order for a square standing on a corner? I'd suggest the polar angle of the center-corner vectors as scalar to sort by. Also, why do you care which order the corners are in?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this is a small part of my bigger problem so let us not discuss the bigger one here. Even for special cases like the one standing on a corner its ok to sort in a way that human vision perceives as top left --> top right --> bottom right -- bottom left ( no hard and fast rule in special cases ) but the algorithm should be accurate for normal cases.

Comment: In that case, just use the polar angle. Between zero and pi/2 is top-right, between pi/2 and pi is top-left etc.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the problem is there are 4Xn coordinate points in random order for n quadrilaterals. i need to identify each individually and order the vertices. knowledge of one quadrilateral won't intersect the other and they are literally stacked one over another ( connected or not connected ) should be used while identifying each.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have uploaded a picture of a typical case. Here we have 8 coordinate points in random order. Here is what needs to be done
1. identify individual quadrilaterals
2. sort the vertices in the order specified earlier.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what would be the bottom right corner of say this ◇.

Comment: If you really only have the corners as a cloud of points, just write an algorithm that extracts groups of four corners that don't overlap with the rest of the cloud. You might have to do some backtracking in case you run into conflicts. Also, there may be multiple solutions, for above example I see at least two. BTW, do you know how to sort by a custom predicate in C++ and do you understand the idea behind the polar angle approach I mentioned? In any case, consider rewriting your question, in particular the C++ code and the tag is completely superfluous if you don't even know an algorithm yet.

Comment: For an arbitrary quadrilateral you are not guaranteed to have 2 top points and 2 bottom points.  What about concave quadrilaterals?

Comment: @Prem If you have to identify the vertices for each quadrilateral can't you just say that the 4 topmost vertices belong to one, then the 4 topmost of those which are left belong to the second, and so on? What does "stacked on each other" mean? From the picture you have posted, what I'm proposing would work.

Comment: As i already mentioned, in my case all four sides could be identified as top left, top right, bottom right  and bottom left ( please refer to the picture ). I need solution in this domain. @UlrichEckhardt my code is working perfectly in practical scenario for one rectangle. This is just an example how I need solution for multiple rectangles. I guess I should use any way ( code, example, words ) to make my question clear. Yes I don't yet have an algorithm that works for multiple rectangles, that is why I posted this question.

Comment: @FabioTurati the vertices are intermixed for two or more rectangles, they are not in order.

Comment: @QuestionC let us fix a problem domain for the quadrilaterals like the ones in the figure I posted. for these it is guaranteed that there are two top and two bottom points.

Comment: Well, you then simply split the vertices you have in two groups of four and then apply the code that is "working perfectly in practical scenario for one rectangle" twice. Seriously, it's all but clear what your problem is, "sort vertices of a rectangle or quadrilateral" isn't it obviously.

Comment: "all four sides could be identified". How?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the vertices are intermixed as I mentioned earlier. Well I got exactly what I was looking for in the answer below. See its not that obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sorting a polygon with `n` vertices

Assuming a coordinate system with x pointing right and y pointing up*, one way would be to have something like this:

```
template<typename It>
void sort_vertices(It begin, It end, typename It::value_type const& center) {
    using point_type = typename It::value_type;

    auto top_down = [](point_type const& a, point_type const& b) { return a.y > b.y; };
    std::sort(begin, end, top_down);
    auto middle = std::find_if(begin, end, [&center](point_type const& a) { return a.y <= center.y; });
    
    auto left_right = [](point_type const& a, point_type const& b) { return a.x < b.x; };
    auto right_left = [](point_type const& a, point_type const& b) { return a.x > b.x; };
    std::stable_sort(begin, middle, left_right);
    std::stable_sort(middle, end, right_left);
}
```

That is, sorting the vertices from top to bottom, and then selecting the ones that are above the center in the range `[begin, middle)`. The remaining `[middle, end)` are the ones on the bottom. At this point you can just stable sort the first ones from left to right and the second ones from right to left.

So considering a polygon like:

[image: A polygon with vertices: (1, 1) (6, 1) (9, 6) (3, 6)]

and feeding the algorithm the vector of points:

> (1, 1) (6, 1) (9, 6) (3, 6)

You would receive:

> (3, 6) (9, 6) (6, 1) (1, 1)

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/425128670f339f73)

This would of course also work with other polygons like:

[image]

feeded as:

> (9, 8) (3, 6) (2, 3) (6, 8) (6, 1) (10, 4)

would yield:

> (3, 6) (6, 8) (9, 8) (10, 4) (6, 1) (2, 3)

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be2e9f91c066abe0)

<sub>* you can of course adapt it differenty if needed :)</sub>

<sub>*Note: pictures have been takes from [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)*</sub>

---

#### Calculating the center of a polygon of `n` vertices

Assuming that we use the same notion of "center" as you have, you can calculate the center accumulating all points and dividing them by the number of points:

```
template<typename It>
typename It::value_type polygon_center(It begin, It end) {
    using point_type = typename It::value_type;
    auto sum = std::accumulate(begin, end, point_type());
    return sum / std::distance(begin, end);
}
```

This makes it possible to define a `sort_vertices` function that only takes a begin and end iterator:

```
template<typename It>
void sort_vertices(It begin, It end) {
    sort_vertices(begin, end, polygon_center(begin, end));
}
```

---

#### Sorting `m` polygons

Given this definition for sorting any number of vertices, we can use a simple algorithm that will iterate over groups of `n` vertices (`n` would be 4 in your case) and performs this transformation:

```
template<typename It>
void sort_polygons(It begin, It end, std::size_t m) {
    for (It cur_begin = begin; cur_begin != end; std::advance(cur_begin, m))
        sort_vertices(cur_begin, std::next(cur_begin, m));
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5968fec2478ba0a5)

---

#### Towards more idiomatic C++

Notice that I've made your code a little bit more like idiomatic C++ :P by changing the following:

- Using `snake_case` for names
- Using templates and iterators
- Using the `<algorithm>` header
- Using the `<numeric>` header